# What should I say? Across or between camera views?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, adverbs

My question is regarding the usage of "across" and "between".

I want to say that a person is viewed by one camera, then disappears and, after a while is sensed by a different cameras.

I wrote

> "...an individual moving across non-overlapping camera views.."

but I have doubts about the usage of "across" here.

Answer (score 2):

I would use "between" here.

> The subject moved between camera locations A and B.

I somehow get the feeling you're potentially talking about something security related (e.g. police report for a company burglary).
I would definitely add in a later sentence that the two camera locations are separated, and that the subject's whereabouts between those two points is uncertain (unless he could not have gone anywhere else, e.g. in a single corridor).

**Edit - update**

I would use "across" when talking about a single camera. E.g:

> The subject walked across the [room] in camera location A. He then moved between locations A and B (meaning you can't specify what happened inbetween, only that he later appeared in location B), because he was later spotted walking across location B.

Comment: +1. I agree that "between" works better there.  If the camera views overlapped, then "across" would work.  *Across* conveys the idea of *continuity*. With non-overlapping views, there's discontinuity.